# C++ Access numbered variables

Tags: c++, templates, macros, variable-names

We have numbered variables like:

```
float my_float_0;
float my_float_1;
float my_float_2;
```

Is there any form of template / macro magic that would let us access these variables by index in a for loop?

Comment: The variable names are auto-generated from external; using arrays instead is sadly not an option.

Comment: That's what arrays are for.

Comment: Why on earth are you not using an array or a vector?

Comment: Whatever auto-generated that does not appear to be particularly useful.

Comment: Naive macro solution: `#define MY_FLOAT_(i) my_float_##i` `for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) MY_FLOAT_(i) = i;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the variables, your only option is some good ol' macro metaprogramming. [Boost.Preprocessor's documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html) is a good place to start - you can iterate over a range of numbers and concatenate them with the `my_float_` token to produce your variable names.

Example *(untested)*:

```
#define SEQ (0)(1)(2)
#define MACRO(r, data, elem) BOOST_PP_CAT(elem, data)

BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(MACRO, my_float_, SEQ) 
// expands to my_float_0 my_float_1 my_float_2
```

By changing what `MACRO` expands to, you can generate code for each variable.